# PrimeVue DataTable Expander with Conditionals

Tags: javascript, vue.js, datatable, conditional-statements, primevue

So I have a DataTable with an array as the value, and the very last column requires an expander, however, certain rows, depending on specifics within the array, require a button in that spot instead of the dropdown for the expander; how can you go about achieving this?

What I have attempted:

```
<Column :expander="true">
 <template #header>
   Expandable
 </template>

 <template #body="slotProps">
  <div v-if="slotProps.data.number === 1">
    <Button />
  </div>
 </template>
</Column>

<template #expansion>
 <div>
  ...
</template>
```

This rendered the button when it was supposed to, however, no dropdown expansion for the other entries.

EDIT: I have enabled the DataTable to not render a dropdown for the specific items by doing the following:

```
<DataTable row-class="rowClass">
...

methods: {
 rowClass(data) {
  return data.number === 1 ? "no-expansion" : ""
 }
}
...

.p-datatable .p-datatable-body > tr.no-expansion > td .p-row-toggler {
 display: none;
}
```

However, I need there to be a PrimeVue `<Button />` in place instead of no display?